# Use of word DID

Tags: word-usage

I have seen a few people writing *Past tense* of verb with ***DID***.. Is it correct? Is it some sort of passive form or something?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Can you give us an example sentence please? :)

Comment: If you mean something like **"I did ate"**, this is incorrect, and a common mistake made by beginning English learners.

Answer (score 1):

*Did* is the "past tense" form of *to do*.

It's used to express simple past tense.

Except for *to be*, all English verbs have at least four basic "forms" or "conjugations", where for regular verbs, two are the same for the five categories below.  Some irregular verbs have a distinct form for four or all five of the categories below (and some irregular verbs like *cut*, *hit*, *set* are the same for all categories).

Here's an example with two regular verbs:

```
Present    Present 3p Singular     Past tense     Present participle     Past participle
---------- ----------------------- -------------- ---------------------- ------------------
walk       walks                   walked         walking                walked
jump       jumps                   jumped         jumping                jumped
```

For the verb *to do*, which is irregular:

```
Present    Present 3p Singular     Past tense     Present participle     Past participle
---------- ----------------------- -------------- ---------------------- ------------------
do         does                    did            doing                  done
```

Passive form is a form of *to be* followed by the past participle form.  So an example of *to do* in passive voice is *"is done"*.